# Microservices application does not start

Tags: node.js, typescript, microservices, nest, monorepo

I just start to learn microservices.And my applications is stop in

```
app.listen(port)
```

I don't know why.I have added

```
.catch()
```

And i did't get anythink.My function seems like this:

```
nx run-many  --target=serve --all --maxParallel=10
```

command start my project.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yq6CO.png)

Can u help me with this issue?

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: In general, any of my microservices stops at the app.listen function. And the last logger.log(app is runnig) is not displayed

Comment: according to image, your port number is already in use. Maybe you have to stop that port first.

Comment: i find the problem.I just forgot to start docker than my server does't response.Thank u guys

Answer (score 0):

As NestJs Microsevice does not listen on any static port, the listen method of the microservice application does not accept any param. 
You will get an error with `app.listen(port)`.

Comment: app.listen is not for Microservices.It is for API

Comment: to init Microservices i use app.init().Sorry for not describing in detail.